# Secure-1PSIDTS and Secure-1PSIDCC Cookies expiring too early

Tags: cookies

Im using the unofficial BardAPI for my python code, and it works perfectly fine for approximately 20 minutes, and then somewhy these cookies changing their values (on the browser), what causes my code fall apart. Any thoughts what could be the problem?

I tried changing browser and creating new google account, but it didn't helped. Expiring date on these cookies is far away, so they are not changing because of expiring. And yes, other users of BardAPI doesn't have the same problem, so it is not the google's security mechanism for sure
Another detail, the Secure-1PSID Cookie doesn't change, it stays the same all the time